# $\nabla f=0$ implies $f$ constant

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

[image]

For the maroon underline, I thought that the existence of partial derivatives did not imply f was differentiable?

For the green part I can't fathom which theorem the lecturer is talking about, so I don't follow this part either.

Comment: MVT = mean value theorem, probably.

Comment: It says MVT AND one of the theorems from lectures

Comment: I think $f$ being differentiable here only means that it has partial derivatives in the x direction and the y direction at every point. The "one of the theorems in the lectures" could be a theorem for the single-variable case saying for any differentiable function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $g' = 0$ implies $g$ is constant.

Comment: I initially had this as an answer, but I will leave it as a comment instead. You are right, existence of partials does not imply differentiablity, but that's not what it's saying. 

We'll consider the simplest case on $\mathbb{R}$ when $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Then for any $a \neq b$, we get $$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = 0$$ and this consequently means that $f(b) = f(a).$ So this must mean that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm. If you have a point $(a,b)$ in the plane, say, and another $(c,d),$ the fact that the $x$ derivative stays $0$ means that $f(a,b) = f(c,b).$ Then, the fact that the $y$ derivative remains $0$ means that $f(c,b) = f(c,d).$ Together, $f(a,b) = f(c,d).$ The argument is the same if the number of variables is larger.

I see, there is a comment to this effect by Nameless, having been deleted as an answer. Well, there you go.